# Get the file path for a static file in django code

Tags: python, django

I have a django application that sends off an email containing image files as MIME attachments. The emails are sent from views.py, but in order to attach the files, I need to get the full path name of the image(s), so python can open them. These files are in the static folder in my app, but I can't seem to find a way that I can get the full path of the file on the filesystem *that works in development mode* - It works fine in production after collecting static, but in dev, it can't find the file as the static files are served from individual app folders in development.

Answer (score 46):

Use [finders-module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#finders-module) of `Django`

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles import finders

result = finders.find('css/base.css')
searched_locations = finders.searched_locations
```

String `result` is the file-system path, and if not found, double check `searched_locations`

Comment: Thanks. This should be the accepted answer, since OP asked for a filesystem path not a URL.

Comment: @SergeRogatch, in production, static files are served by apache/nginx, so this method won't work like debug model.

Comment: This was really helpful for determining where Django was loading static files from, so I could put other files in the right place.  I just used finders.find('.'), and that did the trick.  Thank you!.

Answer (score 24):

**project_dir.url** add to the end of file

```
if DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns(
        '',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': MEDIA_ROOT}),

        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': STATIC_ROOT}),
)
```

**project_dir.settings**

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_debug')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**make dirs *media* & *static_debug* (add them to .gitignore)**

```
project_dir/
    static/
        image.jpg
    settings.py
    urls.py
apps/
    __init__.py
    some_app/
        static/
            some_app/
                css/
                    style.css
media/
static_debug/
```

**Now you can run project or directly**

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

**access from views**

```
from django.templatetags.static import static

static('image.jpg')
static('some_app/css/style.css')
```

**access from templates**

```
{% load staticfiles %}

{% static 'image.jpg' %}
{% static 'some_app/css/style.css' %}
```

Comment: In a view, this returns a relative URI (e.g. to inject into html), not a filesystem path for use with `open()`

Answer (score 8):

After doing lots of mistakes the following thing worked for me..

Suppose you have **following directory structure** (Thanks **@madzohan**)

```
project_dir/
    static/
        image.jpg
    settings.py
    urls.py
apps/
    __init__.py
    some_app/
        static/
            some_app/
                css/
                    style.css
```

And now if you want to get the path of **project_dir/static/image.py then**

In your project_dir/settings.py file define a STATIC_DIR varaible on the file scope like. ( If not done before )

**project_dir/settings.py**

```
import os

# after your other file variables
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Now in your app_name/views.py file from where you want to acess the /static/image.jpg file

**app_name/views.py**

```
import os
from project_dir.settings import STATIC_DIR

# here I want the /static/image.jpg file then
image = os.path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'image.jpg')
```

And then you can have acces to image.jpg file throught image variable

Hope this works well for you

Answer (score 2):

Since you want an app's static, here's what you need!

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles import finders

APP_LABEL = 'app_youre_looking_at'
FILE_NAME = 'file_name_you_want_to_read_or_write.ext'

stores = finders.AppDirectoriesFinder(app_names={APP_LABEL}).storages
print(f'Here it is: {stores[APP_LABEL].path(FILE_NAME)}')
```

The `FILE_NAME` is not required to exist. You can use `stores[APP_LABEL].path('')` to get path only.