# How to load static file in Django Python file

Tags: python, django

I am trying to load a CSV in my Django project. I have a python file located in `/example/hello.py` inside `hello.py` I read a CSV file using Pandas:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static
    productsDF = pd.read_csv(static('example/data/products.csv'))
```

However, for some reason I get a `FileNotFoundError: File b'/static/example/data/products.csv' does not exist`

The CSV file is located in the static directory of my app and it works fine when I want to import static files like CSS in my HTML using `{% load staticfiles } <link href="{% static 'example/hello.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">`

For some reason, it doesn't work in my Python file. How can I get it to work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30430131/get-the-file-path-for-a-static-file-in-django-code

Comment: @ndpu I am trying one of the solutions the answer provided which I also provided in my question, but it is not working

Comment: /static/example/data/ does not look like the static directory of your app. Is the name of our app "example"? Are you running on the dev server?